# Where can I get help testing my program?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where in the Stack Exchange community can I ask for people to simply test my programs? It doesn't even need to be Stack Exchange (though I would prefer that, which is why I made this post in Meta).

No answers would be looked for, just simply a way to request people to test and try to find bugs in my programs and give feedback on how well they work? I'm sorry if this is a copy of anything, but nothing in the suggestions when I wrote this sounded anything similar to my question. In short, here's the question, since I like to restate them for clarity...

> Where in Stack Exchange (or somewhere else if not here) can I ask for people to help test my programs or similar things to that? In a way, you could call it quality-assurance.

Comment: So you're looking for a site where you can hire people to do work for you?

Comment: You can ask for [codereview.se], but I don't know of anywhere on SE where you can get people to *run* code for you.

Comment: @muru Nope. Code Review doesn't test code for you. Please remove your comment.

Comment: @EthanBierlein I did not say it did.

Comment: What about [**StackOverflow Careers**](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)? Seems the best place to go in my opinion.

Comment: Not necessarily where I can _hire_ people, but kindof how one might ask a friend to just test a piece of their program. Unsure why I got the downvote on this, it's a legitimate question and got two legitimate answers. If the downvoter could say _why_ they downvoted, I could use that info for future questions... Also, thanks for the edit help on there, @Nathan Tuggy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stack Exchange is not a job board so I doubt you will find any site that  accepts that question.

There is a site about [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but that ...

> ... is for software quality control experts, automation engineers, and software testers.

I don't expect them to do the testing for you.

One other place that is related to software quality is [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). That site expect you to present working code and ask for specific improvements of your code. No one is going to test run your code and present you with a test-report.

If you're active on a site where you can use chat (requires 20 rep) you could try to leave a request there, but only if the chat room is open for such requests. Most rooms publish their guidance in the room descriptions but I don't know of any room that will be open for your request.

Comment: Accepted as the answer; both the answers were great and presented the same information. Couldn't decide which was necessarily better, so i went with the first one I saw.

Answer (score 9):

Soliciting users for product testing would *not* be appropriate on any Stack Exchange site. Even Code Review (mentioned elsewhere) isn't a good fit for this type of activity. Reviewing code is not the same as software testing, and that is not the intended use for that site.

There's a hypothetical chance that your conversation *might* be welcomed in a chat room related to software discussions. **But be very mindful;** the *norms* of a chat room are determined in large part by the participants; so as you broach the subject, I would be very very conscientious in feeling out if you're activity is welcomed at all. If the conversation is welcomed, have at it.  If it's not, I would respectfully drop the subject and move on. But be careful that your subject isn't *wildly* off-topic for the site and the room you are raising the subject.

Comment: I tried to made clear in my answer that CodeReview is not a good fit. Based on your answer it seems I didn't do that strongly enough. Is that observation correct?

Comment: @rene You made it clear. Code Review was mentioned as a possibility in the comments, so I was just reiterating the point.

Comment: Both the answers were great and presented roughly the same information in their own ways. Couldn't decide which was necessarily better in the time I have, so I went with the first one I saw, which happened to be the other one. I did upvote both, but have to wait for that to show up because of rep. Thank you both for answering.